# Make UIView area unclickable

Tags: ios, ipad

So i have a UIView setup on the Ipad for a small project i am working on. I will be displaying an image or a view on that page. I wanted to know if is it possible to create an invisible border (say 1") around the view that will be unclickable ?
I was thinking of adding a button and disabling it, but i think that would not allow the image to be shown full screen.
I have already setup a recognizer, because i want a three finger swipe to go to the next image. What would be the best approach for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom `UIView` class and override `hitTest:withEvent:`.

```
- UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 25, 25);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point) ? self : nil;
}
```

Adjust the inset to meet your needs.